# Why do we use "key => key" in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am not understanding below code **key => key.addEventListener** can you someone please explain this line.

```
const keys = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.key'));
keys.forEach(key => key.addEventListener('transitionend', removeTransition));
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer can be found by [reading the fine manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Answer (score 1):

This (`keys.forEach(key=>....)`) is equivalent to the following:

```
keys.forEach(function(key){ key.addEventListener('transitionend', removeTransition)});
```

Comparing the latter with the one with the *arrow function expression*, `key => key.addEventListener('transitionend', removeTransition)`, I think that the version with the arrow is more succint.

As it is stated [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) :

> An arrow function expression has a **shorter syntax** than a function
>   expression and does not bind its own this, arguments, super, or
>   new.target. These function expressions are best suited for non-method
>   functions, and they cannot be used as constructors.

Shorter syntaxt definitely means more readable code. More readable codes means more easier to catch up with quickly and a sequence more easier to be maintained.

Comment: To expand a bit on this, `=>` is the syntax for [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Answer (score 0):

The `=>` is called an arrow function. It's a shorthand method for defining a function.

```
keys.forEach(function(key){console.log(key)})
```

can be expressed as an arrow function with

```
keys.forEach(key => {console.log(key)})
```

The `key` is the first parameter passed from `forEach`, in this case the `currentValue`. You could expand this if needed to:

```
keys.forEach((currentValue, index, array) => {...})
```

if you needed access to the other parameters available in `forEach`.

For more details on [Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) see the [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Answer (score 0):

```
key => key.addEventListener('transitionend', removeTransition)
```

is equivalent to something like

```
function(key){
return key.addEventListener('transitionend', removeTransition) // binding custom event to event listener
}()
```